# powershell - matching for whitespace

Tags: powershell

I want to match the group called "Teams (E1) Licensed Users" in below command. But, it does not return anything for `$licenseGroup3` variable. So, it's null.

```
   $licenseGroup = ''
   $licenseGroup = Get-ADUser -Identity $($user.UserPrincipalName.Split("@")[0]) -Properties memberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberOf
   }
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
   # Grabs Users that are a member of our Licensing Group
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
   $licenseGroup3 = ''
   $licenseGroup3 = $licenseGroup | Where {($_ -match "Teams (E1) Licensed Users")}
```

- if there are `(E1)` between ad group name such as Teams (E1) Licensed Users it does not works.

licencegroup:

```
   CN=Teams (E1) Licensed Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local
   CN=Test_Groups,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local
```

Comment: Show examples of `$licenseGroup`.

Comment: The code in your question works. An array like `$licenseGroup = "CN=Teams Licensed Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local","CN=Test_Groups,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local"` and `$licenseGroup | Where {($_ -match "Teams Licensed Users")}` gives one result, as expected `"CN=Teams Licensed Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local"`. Your actual code and the code of your question are different.

Comment: I have updated my $licenseGroup.

Comment: Should not be a surprise that `"Teams Licensed Users"` does not match `"Teams (E1) Licensed Users"`, and it's not because of the whitespace. You will have to think about your question some more.

Comment: :) I have updated my question again.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Hang on.

Comment: @Arbelac `(` and `)` needs to be escaped: `$_ -match [regex]::Escape("Teams (E1) Licensed Users")`

Comment: Maybe `$_ -match "Teams.*?Licensed Users"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator expects a regular expression. And the parentheses `(` / `)` have special meaning in regex, they need to be escaped.

So either like this:

```
... | where { $_ -match "Teams \(E1\) Licensed Users" }
```

or you use a function that works with substrings instead of regex, for example `.Contains()`:

```
... | where { $_.Contains("Teams (E1) Licensed Users") }
```